# How to get the attribute value of a child element?

Tags: jquery, html

I need get attribute 'actualCastId' of the image element in div hair, eye...

```
<div class="char">   
    <img src="images/avatar/char.png">
    <div id="hair" class="charH"><img src="images/avatar/h1.png" data-actualCastId="1" width="99px"></div>
    <div id="eye" class="charE"><img src="images/avatar/e1.png" data-actualCastId="1" width="99px"></div>
    <div id="nose" class="charN"><img src="images/avatar/n1.png" data-actualCastId="1" width="99px"></div>
    <div id="mouth" class="charM"><img src="images/avatar/m1.png" data-actualCastId="1" width="99px"></div>
    <div id="imputedName"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying use this, but it just write undefined.

```
charH = $("#hair").find('img').attr("actualCastId");
charN = $("#eye").find("img").attr("actualCastId");
charE = $("#nose").find("img").attr("actualCastId");
charM = $("#mouth").find("img").attr("actualCastId");
```

Comment: `$("#hair").find('img').attr("data-actualCastId");` OR `$("#hair").find('img').data("actualCastId");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

**Solution 1**

```js
charH = $("#hair").find('img').attr("data-actualCastId");
charN = $("#eye").find("img").attr("data-actualCastId");
charE = $("#nose").find("img").attr("data-actualCastId");
charM = $("#mouth").find("img").attr("data-actualCastId");

console.log("charH:", charH);
console.log("charN:", charN);
console.log("charE:", charE);
console.log("charHM:", charM);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="char">   
    <img src="images/avatar/char.png">
    <div id="hair" class="charH"><img src="images/avatar/h1.png" data-actualCastId="1" width="99px"></div>
    <div id="eye" class="charE"><img src="images/avatar/e1.png" data-actualCastId="1" width="99px"></div>
    <div id="nose" class="charN"><img src="images/avatar/n1.png" data-actualCastId="1" width="99px"></div>
    <div id="mouth" class="charM"><img src="images/avatar/m1.png" data-actualCastId="1" width="99px"></div>
    <div id="imputedName"></div>
</div>
```

**Solution 2**

```js
charH = $("#hair").find('img').data("actualcastid");
charN = $("#eye").find("img").data("actualcastid");
charE = $("#nose").find("img").data("actualcastid");
charM = $("#mouth").find("img").data("actualcastid");

console.log("charH:" , charH);
console.log("charN:" , charN);
console.log("charE:" , charE);
console.log("charM:" , charM);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="char">   
  <img src="images/avatar/char.png">
  <div id="hair" class="charH"><img src="images/avatar/h1.png" data-actualcastid="1" width="99px"></div>
  <div id="eye" class="charE"><img src="images/avatar/e1.png" data-actualcastid="1" width="99px"></div>
  <div id="nose" class="charN"><img src="images/avatar/n1.png" data-actualcastid="1" width="99px"></div>
  <div id="mouth" class="charM"><img src="images/avatar/m1.png" data-actualcastid="1" width="99px"></div>
  <div id="imputedName"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access `data-actualCastId`

```
charH = $("#hair img").attr("data-actualCastId");
charN = $("#hair img").attr("data-actualCastId");
charE = $("#hair img").attr("data-actualCastId");
charM = $("#hair img").attr("data-actualCastId");
```

Or you can use [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)  but for this attr after data must be in lower case. 
 i.e `actualcastid`

```
<div class="char">   
    <img src="images/avatar/char.png">
    <div id="hair" class="charH"><img src="images/avatar/h1.png" data-actualcastid="1" width="99px"></div>
    <div id="eye" class="charE"><img src="images/avatar/e1.png" data-actualcastid="1" width="99px"></div>
    <div id="nose" class="charN"><img src="images/avatar/n1.png" data-actualcastid="1" width="99px"></div>
    <div id="mouth" class="charM"><img src="images/avatar/m1.png" data-actualcastid="1" width="99px"></div>
    <div id="imputedName"></div>
</div>

charH = $("#hair img").data("actualcastid");
charN = $("#hair img").data("actualcastid");
charE = $("#hair img").data("actualcastid");
charM = $("#hair img").data("actualcastid");
```

Comment: Also, you can probably merge your queries: $("#hair img").data("...")

Comment: @realbart ; Updated my answer. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

To get the contents of the attribute data-id you have to use

1. eg1: $(this).attr("data-id"); eg2: $(this).data("id");

Comment: putting code with out explanation is not a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `attr`

```
charH = $("#hair").find('img').attr("data-actualCastId");
charN = $("#eye").find("img").attr("data-actualCastId");
charE = $("#nose").find("img").attr("data-actualCastId");
charM = $("#mouth").find("img").attr("data-actualCastId");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
charH = $("#hair img').data("actualCastId");
charN = $("#eye img").data("actualCastId");
charE = $("#nose img").data("actualCastId");
charM = $("#mouth img").data("actualCastId");
```